# how to give opacity to iframe in ie 9-11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I gave opacity to li tag, and on hover opacity is 1. In chrome, mozilla opacity is ok. But In ie 9-11 no opacity. I have tried to put div with absolute position in it but no success, also tried to give `background-color:transparent` to iframe but again no success. Here is my html code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QALRgeSoZRs" width="300" height="150" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>                
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is css code:

```
.video_list ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @CraftdMC css is added

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for that, maybe this will be useful for others

here is my updated code:

```
<iframe style="background: transparent;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QALRgeSoZRs?wmode=transparent" width="300" height="150" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

just added `?wmode=transparent` this parameter.

But now there is one problem onhover can't remove transparency can anyone suggest anything about that?